# JS - Replace language

Tags: javascript

i have following line in my JS-File:

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "en",
```

I want simply change the line in:

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "de",
```

or

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "es",
```

or

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "fr",
```

or

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "la",
```

or

```
   language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : "it",
```

And I want to replace the line in my js-file when I choose a language:

```
   <select id="type" name="type">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="la">Latin</option>
    <option value="it">Italian</option>
   </select>
```

But I have no idea how to realize it :/ Someone can help? And one tip: I don't want to change the language for the visitor in the frontend. I just want to change it to have my whole script in the chosen language.

**UPDATE**

I have following in my JS-File:

```
   // Global Var in JS (placed on top)
   var LANGUAGE = "en";
   function languageChange(){ 
   LANGUAGE = document.getElementById("selectLanguage").value;
   }
```

And I have following in my HTML-File:

```
   <p style="float:left"><input style="border:1px solid #bbb" type="submit" value="Choose language" id="submit"></p>
   <p style="float:right; padding-right:20px">
   <select id="selectLanguage" onchange="languageChange">
   <option value="en">English</option>
   <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
   <option value="es">Español</option>
   <option value="fr">Français</option>
   <option value="la">Lingua latina</option>
   <option value="it">Italiano</option>
   </select>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Enter" id="submit"></p>
```

And it don't works.

Comment: Are you using server side languages (PHP, asp, python ..)?

Comment: PHP, yes. You think it's better to realize it with preg_replace?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can keep client settings on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var languageEnum = {
  english: "en",
  german: "de",
  spanish: "es",
  french: "fr",
  latin: "la",
  italian: "it"
};

var pageConfiguration = {
  language: languageEnum.english; // note that this could be a user preference too and you could check the browser's language
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type").change(function(){
    pageConfiguration.language = $(this).val();
  });
});

  //...
  language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : pageConfiguration.language,
  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//GLOBAL
var LANGUAGE = "en"; // if english is default


//on bodyload
$("#type").change(function(){
  LANGUAGE = $(this).val();
});


//wherever you want to use it
language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : LANGUAGE,
```

For the Comments:

1. enum just wasting ressources (in my opinion ==> btw thanks ;) )
2. use my code is based on jquery
3. on bodyload can be put into jquery on domready, html on bodyload, etc

For pure JS:

```
// HTML:

<select id="selectLanguage" onchange="languageChange">

// JS
//// Global Var in JS (placed on top)
var LANGUAGE = "en";

//// function placed anywhere
function languageChange(){
    LANGUAGE = document.getElementById("selectLanguage").value;
}

//// wherever you want to use the line
language : (div.lang && div.lang != "") ? div.lang : LANGUAGE
```

BTW:
    //onload events
    //// Html way

```
//or
//// JQ way
$(document).ready(function{})

// etc...
```

Comment: I would put the language variable into a configuration object.

Comment: But +1 for the answer :)

Comment: This looks nice. Thanks. And I just add my HTML-Code (in my Question)?

Comment: Bodyload... Don't works my JS-File don't built the site if i put it in, maybe a syntax fault? May you can say what I put in bodyload?

Comment: What is the error? The answer takes into consideration implicitly that jQuery is linked in your page.

Comment: @Alerty I think this is jQuery? I need JavaScript, please. And I tried all combinations and nothing work for me :(

Comment: @Pika // May you can help?