# Changing the language without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying to change the language of my site directly without reloading the page when i click on any of my three language-flags (German, french and English).

To correspond with the language I am saving a cookie called `lang` after clicking on a flag.
I've got an function `LangText($de, $fr, $en);` that displays the right text depending on what the clients cookie has stored in.

This is my function:

```
function LangText($de, $fr, $us){
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["lang"]) || $_COOKIE["lang"] == "de") echo $de;
    else if($_COOKIE["lang"] == "fr") echo $fr;
    else if($_COOKIE["lang"] == "us") echo $us;
    else return 0;
}
```

Until now i was redirecting the user on a php that stored the cookie in, and redirected the user to the previous site.
is there a possibility of realising this without any reloadings?

Comment: If you've never heard of Ajax, then that would be an option.

Comment: I already heard of ajax, but I don't have an idea of realising this and I have not found any useable answers on the world wide web for this.

Comment: If you give anything about searchability of your site, then you should not put the language into a cookie (search engines don’t send cookies), but have it be part of the URL. And since it would be a totally different resource then, simply linking to it would make a lot more sense. This whole “I don’t want to reload my page, I want to just switch out the content” philosophy is quite a load of BS in a lot of cases, and this here is one of them IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your honest opinion but my website is not going to be listed on search engines because our company is marketing theirselves using other methods. I just want to optimize our website dynamically.

Comment: To "change the language without reloading" means you'd need to load all available languages in one page, then display the one the user chooses. Otherwise, you must get the new content somehow.

Comment: With the function on my startpost I am lading all languages and only displaying the one the cookie tells me. so, how can I realise this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17639441/ and http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1201302-How-to-send-current-language-with-jquery-ajax-to-php-script and http://raki-kums.blogspot.ca/2011/09/multilingual-html-pages-using-basic.html they might be of help.

Comment: _“website is not going to be listed on search engines because our company is marketing theirselves using other methods”_ – still, there’s other problems as well with using the cookie approach. A user calling a bookmark on a different computer, or sending a link to someone else or sharing it on a social network f.e. – all of these are highly likely to show up in another language version than the user had intended. With the language in the URL, all of that would be no problem …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also strongly recommend language specific URIs, but this should work. Requires **jQuery**.

```
function changeLanguage(lang){
    // Replace "lang" cookie with new language
    document.cookie = "lang="+lang;
    // Get html of current URI and replace page contents.
    $("body").load(window.location.href);
}

// Call this to switch to German, for example
changeLanguage("de");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're managing your multi-language site only with PHP, as PHP is a server side language, you'll need to reload (because you need to go to the server to get the new page calculated).

There is nothing wrong with this.
On your application bootstrap you must look for the language cookie, check its value and set the language environment value.

I would recommend you to manage multi-language withou cookies because cookies are annoying and now you have to deal with legal policies about cookies usage.

You can manage multi-language, just using an URI path like `en/` or `pt/`.
Almost all PHP frameworks do this for you out-of-the-box.

Comment: How do you mean PHP can do this out of the box for me?  Is there an easy possibility like using a file like this?: `xxx.com/abc.php/de` ?

Comment: I wrote "PHP frameworks". Have a look at, for example, [Yii Framewrok - Multilanguage and SEO friendly](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/579/multilanguage-and-seo-friendly/)